# R, SciKitLearn, and Statsmodels Provide Different Multiple Linear Regression Fits

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, linear-regression, statsmodels

I am attempting to make a multiple linear regression model to predict a quantity called CTRRMAX.  This MLR model is purely a predictive model - I do not need to understand the significance or relationship the predictors have to the outcome variable.  I just want the model to explain as much of the variance as possible.

I learned how to do regression analysis in R, so I was doing most of my transformations and feature selection there.  When I tried to embed it within the Python code I normally work with, scikitlearn provided me with a completely different model, as did statsmodels. I don't understand why I would get different R-squareds, coefficients, and intercepts from all these different packages.  Should they not all be the same?

I've provided the code between the different packages.

R Code:

```r
final_MLRmodel = lm(ctrrmax~cape+area+newrhsurf+newlcl+mucape+ecape+shear1+newpsurf+newmaxcape+newrhcolint+newshear3)
summary(final_MLRmodel)
```

The output gives me R2=0.4593 and adjR2=0.3999

ScikitLearn Code:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.DataFrame([CAPE, AREA, newRHsurf, newLCL, MUCAPE, ECAPE, shear1, newPsurf, newmaxCAPE, newrh_colint, newshear3, CTRRMAX])
df = df.transpose()

X = df[df.columns[0:-1]]
y = df[df.columns[-1]]

lm = LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(X, y)

y_pred = model.predict(X)
R2 = model.score(X,y)
print('R2: ', model.score(X,y))

n = len(CTRRMAX)
p=np.shape(X)[1]
adjr2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p-1)
print('adjR2: ', adjr2)
```

The output gives me R2=0.1855 and adjR2=0.0959.

Statsmodels:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
X1 = sm.add_constant(X)
mod = sm.OLS(y,X1)
res = mod.fit()
res.summary()
```

The output gives me R2=-7.283 and adjR2=-7.283.

I've confirmed a million times that all models are reading the exact same data even after transformation.  I thought maybe it was an issue with multicollinearity, but if I only want a predictive model, then I didn't think I had to care about multicollinearity?  Any help would be appreciated.

This model also obviously requires a dataset to run.  This is my first stack overflow question, and I couldn't figure out how to attach the .csv file that I use to transfer my data from Python to R.  I've posted just the first 20 datapoints for each variable here, in the hopes that the whole dataset is not required.

```py
CTRRMAX = np.array(0.65109549, 0.57082317, 0.66105562, 0.65956423, 0.62482739,
       0.66715294, 0.58653562, 0.67174625, 0.64250845, 0.48642454,
       0.77204295, 0.66184076, 0.68038761, 0.73653454, 0.60328276,
       0.62336814, 0.64258676, 0.65066922, 0.82871873, 0.58368109)
CAPE = np.array(2160., 3030., 2090., 1420., 2540.,  470., 1730., 2310., 2010.,
       5020., 1490., 2830.,  510., 1310., 3800., 1700., 1660., 1990.,
        130., 3080.)
AREA = np.array(266., 175., 122., 161., 165., 225.,  86., 129., 295., 316.,  44.,
       116., 244., 253., 118., 138., 128.,  69., 118., 117.)
newRHsurf = np.array(0.37423277, -0.38957954, -0.00965352, -0.74678448,  0.01749659,
        0.78598837,  0.40301939, -0.99305805,  0.57022447,  0.99996833,
       -0.40080868,  0.59670993,  0.8575545 , -0.26668987,  0.81043055,
       -0.15807503,  0.7954259 , -0.86284556, -0.23866762,  0.1054419)
newLCL = np.array(-0.99553022,  0.09343053,  0.80974088, -0.99510076, -0.95194702,
        0.16104252,  0.8352307 ,  0.99146248, -0.83244151, -0.25468422,
       -0.78162311,  0.13424665, -0.55608987, -0.31989455, -0.4858867 ,
        0.78814695, -0.3772229 , -0.14639698, -0.49059305,  0.9434852)
MUCAPE = np.array(3231.9094098 , 2722.89503908, 2434.98996265, 2483.8618223 ,
       1534.22930423, 2274.16312798, 1758.04659665, 2013.51926427,
       1852.74436288, 3849.84084006, 1538.14989687, 2040.98226786,
       1049.41283138, 1623.10054915, 4055.06571398, 2386.93537232,
       2421.36562901, 3093.63218601, 1886.79025799, 3033.74984899)
ECAPE = np.array(544.31677561, 628.24486587, 198.8664456 ,  27.78930588,
       726.19478451,  28.43822235, 180.08772011, 267.41910501,
       205.58738719, 282.76765822, 140.42604251, 453.39778625,
       110.01754724, 173.23091256, 546.4515334 ,  28.88800818,
        32.49516751, 194.49062916,  47.18208684, 150.4724515)
shear1 = np.array(0.38087247, 1.57931439, 1.39215283, 1.10672164, 3.02872954,
       1.80076502, 0.9350142 , 1.9858369 , 0.56996634, 3.39201731,
       1.86925209, 1.74190136, 0.40244472, 2.16668611, 2.02204818,
       1.50670497, 1.07298262, 0.74519335, 1.04231893, 1.52101836)
newPsurf = np.array(0.12141161,  0.99513855, -0.47831087,  0.37072577, -0.92267433,
        0.30656576, -0.22574095, -0.99994693, -0.45593397,  0.95358944,
       -0.9355281 , -0.67766388, -0.84796369,  0.69423688,  0.99605423,
        0.86181924, -0.30228107, -0.3340524 ,  0.02340334,  0.99402057)
newmaxCAPE = np.array(0.59753941,  0.63973417, -0.88611046,  0.97564725, -0.56573558,
        0.99420651,  0.69055665,  0.18575401,  0.94000581,  0.32183912,
        0.98409834, -0.99429748,  0.96010656,  0.7027577 ,  0.97306961,
        0.9949444 ,  0.99237209, -0.97644958,  0.04583703,  0.99022841)
newrh_colint = np.array(4.35888606e+18, 3.47399496e+18, 3.33191607e+18, 3.72920308e+18,
       3.61121221e+18, 3.17535430e+18, 3.59729890e+18, 2.86802689e+18,
       3.44806618e+18, 5.08126931e+18, 2.34607596e+18, 3.28603005e+18,
       2.03731238e+18, 2.78882246e+18, 4.56923554e+18, 3.21237248e+18,
       3.41041888e+18, 3.53788584e+18, 2.80536323e+18, 4.32299498e+18)
newshear3 = np.array(0.44118218, -0.99932764,  0.42862348,  0.65427145, -0.94152187,
        0.86240296,  0.38829232, -0.33614615,  0.83542138, -0.46978768,
        0.6141936 , -0.61328793,  0.77510501,  0.8593079 , -0.03691697,
        0.99619598,  0.55651457,  0.97479817,  0.99382273,  0.23179711)
```

Comment: Does this cut-down dataset show the same behavior as your larger dataset?

Comment: show the full statsmodels summary. R2 is supposed to be in interval [0, 1]. something is strange

Comment: Do you get the same coefficients in all the models?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're running into an issue of variable scaling. The `newrh_colint` variable is 10^18 times bigger than the other variables.

If I load your variables to predict like so:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([CAPE, AREA, newRHsurf, newLCL, MUCAPE, ECAPE, shear1, newPsurf, newmaxCAPE, newrh_colint, newshear3, CTRRMAX])
df = df.transpose()
df[9] *= 1e-18
```

Then newrh_colint has roughly the same magnitude as the other variables, and I get an R squared much more similar to what R is producing.

Why does this matter? Theoretically, floating point numbers have just as much relative accuracy at 10^18 as they have at 10^0, and multiplying one of your X variables by a constant shouldn't change the result. However, I suspect that the `newrh_colint` column is so much larger than the others that the result is a nearly singular matrix.

If you wanted a solution that automatically scales variables so they're of the same magnitude, you could use [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Note that StandardScaler changes the interpretation of your regression coefficients. Before, a coefficient of 0.5 means that an increase of 1 in the input variable means an increase of 0.5 in the output, but if you use StandardScaler, then a coefficient of 0.5 means that an increase of 1 standard deviation results in a 0.5 increase in the output.